# Which papers exemplify the attrition of the L1 in the interface of language modules?

Tags: reference-request, language-acquisition, multilingualism

I’m intending to write my BA thesis on language attrition and I have a problem finding info. So I’m looking for papers that exemplify the attrition of the L1 in the interface of language modules (morphology,semantics,syntax). The L2 should be English and for the L1 any language is ok.

Comment: Searching some sites of scholarly papers (e.g. https://researchgate.net or https://scholar.google.com ) for "language attrition" or "language attrition English" gives a plethora of results to start with.

Comment: See also https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/15150/9781

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge amount of information out there, the problem is deciding what specific information you are looking for. For example, you could focus on indigenous (Amerindian) language attrition in the US; or attrition of Persian among second or third generation immigrants in Canada. Then you could google "arabic language attrition in the US" which would lead you to papers like [this](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED614077.pdf). Just looking for "language attrition isn't going to lead you to anything particularly useful, I recommend narrowing the search down in terms of what languages, especially ones with enough speakers that someone is likely to have studied the matter (e.g. "matumbi language attrition" will not give you anything useful, likewise "piraha language attrition").